# Cannot insert image into xpage richtext ckeditor when using custom datasource

Tags: ckeditor, xpages

I am attempting to use my own datasource in an xpage application.
The datasource is a managed-bean which implements the `com.ibm.xsp.model.DataObject interface`.
Everything is working fine, including text in the `CKEditor`, except for images in the `CKEditor`.
Here's what appears to happen when you upload an image using the `CKEditor` with a `DominoDocument` as datasource:

1. Image is uploaded.
2. Image is persisted in the `DominoDocument` (or somewhere temporarily, until the document is saved)
3. A javascript callback is sent back to the CKEditor in the response, e.g.

   ```
   window.parent.CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(0, "/NestedRichText.nsf/xsp/.ibmmodres/persistence/DominoDoc-5-Body/list-remove_1358252554024.gif");
   ```

Using my datasource, I see that an object of type `com.ibm.xsp.component.UIInputRichtText.EmbeddedIMage` is set as the value on the `RichText` field when the image is uploaded.
The problem is I don't really know how to deal with this object.  I've looked at the `UIInputRichText` and `DominoDocument` objects and have seen a few promising methods.  But I haven't been able to get this to work.

Has anyone else gotten this to work?

Comment: You probably want to overwrite that callback and implement your own little routine. The CK Editor website might know details

Comment: @stwissel: The CSJS code sent back to the client is just a call for CKEditor which sets the path in the file upload dialog. The URL is the path to the temp folder on the server.

Comment: @stwissel: It is clear to me what the callback is doing.  I'm actually more interested what is happening server side: how am I supposed to implement the persisting of the image server-side and how can I send the proper info back in the callback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently only the DominoDocument datasource is supported by the Rich Text control for processing of embedded images.  You can create your own custom solution though - to do this you will need to subclass XspInputRichText to provide your own processAjaxRequest implementation.  A .xsp-config file to register your specialized subclass is required, along with the subclass implementation.  All of this can be done inside an application or in a separate library.  Email me directly if you want further details on achieving this.

See the following OpenNTF project for a fully worked example:

http://www.openntf.org/p/xpages%20rich%20text%20editor%20evolution

Comment: Great to see you answering here Tony. Hopefully you can share as much information here as possible instead of e-mailing it privately.

Comment: @Tony: Thanks for the tip, I will get in touch and see if I can get this to work. I'll then share the solution here.

Comment: See the following OpenNTF project for a fully worked example:

http://www.openntf.org/p/xpages%20rich%20text%20editor%20evolution